# Open all AdMob ads links in new activity?

Tags: android, admob

Is there anyway to direct all admob ads to open in a new webview activity within my app instead of opening to a browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as a publisher.

On Android, the user can just press the back button to get back to  your app anyways. On iOS, the `openUrl` method in the [AdMob API for Ads](http://media.admob.com/api/v1/docs/) supports the ability for the advertiser to open the url in the Mobile Safari app instead of the in-app browser.